# Haskell GHCi prints lazy sequence but Scala REPL doesn't

Tags: scala, haskell

I would to print out a stream of numbers but the following code only prints out the first number in the sequence:

```
for ( n <- Stream.from(2) if n % 2 == 0 ) yield println(n)
2
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Unit] = Stream((), ?)
```

In Haskell the following *keeps* printing out numbers until interrupted and I would like similar behaviour in Scala:

```
naturals = [1..]
[n | n <- naturals, even n]
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,
```

Comment: basically, this expression constructs a `Stream` of `()`. So you get one value, `2`, printed only because scala repl needed to print `res4: .... = Stream((), ?)`, for which just one `()` needed computing. If you remove `yield`, it will be a different loop and you should get an infinite stream of even numbers printed.

Comment: Your Haskell example **does not** print numbers. You can demonstrate this by compiling it from source, rather than using the repl - it will appear to do nothing. The Haskell repl simply displays the contents as a convenience, where the Scala repl does not. The code in Haskell to print out an infinite sequence of even numbers would look more like `forM [n | n <- naturals, even n] (putStrLn . show)`, where the composed functions `(putStrLn . show)` contains the actual logic to print a number to the screen (the same way `println` does in Scala)

Comment: I got the answer from looking at all the answers: (1) in the REPL, Scala doesn't print infinite streams by default, so you need to explicitly ask it to print. (2) To explicitly ask it to print (either in the REPL or in a program): if `s` is a `Stream`, then use `s foreach println` to print the elements of `s` one line at a time. (3) But the Scala interpreter is stupid and hitting Ctrl-C kills the interpreter (instead of the loop you're running), so if `s` is too long (or infinite), you may want to print only a bounded number of terms.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of yielding just println (why would one want infinite sequence of Unit's?):

```
for ( n <- Stream.from(2) if n % 2 == 0 ) println(n)
```

If you really want that infinite sequence of Units, force result:

```
val infUnit = for ( n <- Stream.from(2) if n % 2 == 0 ) yield println(n)
infUnit.force // or convert to any other non-lazy collection
```

Though, eventually, it will crash program (due to large length of materialized sequence).

Comment: The type of the result should be List[Int] but I was experimenting with println to see what is happening. Please could you update your code so that it outputs a list of ints as the Haskell code does?

Comment: @I.K. do you really want to have *infinite* list? should it be forced or not?

Comment: I guess I am confusing matters. To clarify: With Haskell, I don't really need to specify any additional semantics to generate an infinite list of integers. The enumeration `[1..]` does that nicely. When I use that lazy list in the list comprehension it keeps giving integers until the Haskell interpreter is interrupted. I would like the same behaviour in Scala. I thought that `Stream.from(1)` would give me that infinite lazy sequence (without forcing, or specifying any additional semantics) but it appears it does not.

Comment: In the end, the Scala code should replicate the Haskell behaviour and return List[Int].

Comment: *I thought that Stream.from(1) would give me that infinite lazy sequence (without forcing, or specifying any additional semantics)* That really confuses me. `Stream.from ...` will indeed give you **lazy** sequence -- it is so lazy that it does not print itself fully. Now, in order to print it out you need to remove lazyness, or in other words **force** it. Yes, there is some difference between them -- Haskell is lazy by default, scala is eager by default and, unlike Haskell, it makes distinction between *eager* List (aka, just `List`) and *lazy* List (aka `Stream`).

Answer (score 2):

The result type of a *for comprehension* is a collection of the same type of the collection in the first clause. [See the flatMap function signature](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream@flatMap%5BB,That%5D%28f%3aA=>scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce%5BB%5D%29%28implicitbf%3ascala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom%5Bscala.collection.immutable.Stream%5BA%5D,B,That%5D%29%3aThat)

So the result of a

```
for ( n <- Stream.from(2) .....
```

is a collection of type Stream[_] which is lazy so you have to pull the element values or actions out.

Look at the result types:

```
scala> :type for( n <- Stream.from(2)) yield n
scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int]

scala> :type for( n <- List(1,2,3)) yield n
List[Int]

scala> :type for( n <- Set(1,2,3)) yield n
scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
```

---

To print out numbers until interrupted try this:

```
Stream.from(2).filter(_ % 2 == 0) foreach println
```

Its type grants us it will work:

```
scala> :type Stream.from(2).filter(_ % 2 == 0) foreach println
Unit
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```
for (n <- Stream.from(2) if n % 2 == 0) yield n
```

(because `yield println(n)` will always `yield ()` with a side effect of printing `n`)

This gives you the collection you want. However, Scala, unlike Haskell, doesn't evaluate all members of a (lazy) list when you print the lazy list (a `Stream`). But you can convert it into a non-lazy list using `.toList`. However, you won't see the same infinite printing behaviour in Scala as it will try to build the entire (infinite) list first before printing anything at all.

Basically there is no way to get the exact same combination of semantics and behaviour in Scala compared to Haskell when printing infinite lists using the built-in `toString` infrastructure.

*P.S.*

```
for (n <- Stream.from(2) if n % 2 == 0) yield n
```

is expressed more shortly as

```
Stream.from(2).filter(_ % 2 == 0)
```